# Calculating trace by determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, trace

Let $F(x,y)=xyI_p$ where $I_p$ is $p$-dimensional identity matrix.
I want to calculate

$ \operatorname{tr} \left( F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}  F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right) \quad $ and $ \quad \operatorname{tr}\left( F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}  F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)$

where $\operatorname{tr}( )$ denotes the trace operator.
It is straightforward to show that

$\operatorname{tr}\left( F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}  F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)=\frac{p}{x^2}, \quad $ 
and   $\quad \operatorname{tr}\left( F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}  F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)=\frac{p}{xy}$.

I want to obtain these in another way. Since $d^2\log|F|=-\operatorname{tr}(F^{-1}dFF^{-1}dF)$ and $\log|F|=p\log(x)+p\log(y)$, it follows that

$$\operatorname{tr}\left( F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}  F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)=\frac{\partial^2 \log|F|}{\partial x^2}=\frac{p}{x^2}.$$

However, we have

$$\operatorname{tr}\left( F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}  F^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)=\frac{\partial^2 \log|F|}{\partial x \partial y}=0$$

which is different from the above result. I don't see what is the problem.

Comment: $\delta^2 \log|F| = {\rm tr}(\color{red}{F^{-1}\delta^2F} - F^{-1}\delta FF^{-1}\delta F) $